# Issues related to Shiny from RStudio

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to insert a table and graph when selecting an option defined in Shiny from RStudio. When selecting the option "Select all properties" I would like to show Table1 and Graph1 on the same page. And if I press the option "Exclude properties that produce less than L and more than S" to present just Table2 and Graph2. I left an executable script below to show the table and figure I want to insert in my shiny code. I just want to display the table and figure when selecting one of the options that I mentioned above.

**Executable script and shiny code**

```
library(shiny)
library(kableExtra)
library(ggplot2)
library(factoextra)

#database
df<-structure(list(Latitude = c(-23.8, -23.8, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9,  -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, 
                                + -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9), Longitude = c(-49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.7, 
                                                                                    + -49.7, -49.7, -49.7, -49.7, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6), Waste = c(526, 350, 526, 469, 285, 175, 175, 350, 350, 175, 350, 175, 175, 364, 
                                                                                                                                                         + 175, 175, 350, 45.5, 54.6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -19L))

Q1<-matrix(quantile(df$Waste, probs = 0.25))
df_Q1<-subset(df,Waste>Q1[1])
df_Q1

#cluster
d<-dist(df_Q1)
fit.average<-hclust(d,method="average")
clusters<-cutree(fit.average,k=4)
df_Q1$cluster<-clusters
df_Q1$properties<-names(clusters)

#calculate sum waste
dc<-aggregate(df_Q1[,"Waste"],list(cluster=clusters),sum)
colnames(dc)<-c("cluster","Sum_Waste")
head(dc)

#calculate mean waste
dd<-aggregate(df_Q1[,"Waste"],list(cluster=clusters),mean)
colnames(dd)<-c("cluster","Mean_Waste")
head(dd)

#merge everything
df_table <- Reduce(merge, list(df_Q1, dc, dd))


#make table1
table1<- kable(df_table[order(df_table$cluster, as.numeric(df_table$properties)),c(5,2,3,4,1,6,7)], align = "c", row.names = FALSE) %>%
    kable_styling(full_width = FALSE) %>%
    column_spec(1, bold = TRUE) %>%
    collapse_rows(columns = 5:7, valign = "middle")

#make table2
table2<-kable(df_table[order(df_table$cluster, as.numeric(df_table$properties)),c(3,2,4,6,7)], align = "c", row.names = FALSE) %>%
    kable_styling(full_width = FALSE) %>%
    column_spec(1, bold = TRUE) %>%
    collapse_rows(columns = 3:5, valign = "middle")

#make table 3
table3<- kable(df_table[order(df_table$cluster, as.numeric(df_table$properties)),c(4,3,2,5,1,7,6)], align = "c", row.names = FALSE) %>%
    kable_styling(full_width = FALSE) %>%
    column_spec(1, bold = TRUE) %>%
    collapse_rows(columns = 5:7, valign = "middle")

#make table 4
table4<- kable(df_table[order(df_table$cluster, as.numeric(df_table$properties)),c(7,6,3,4,1,2,5)], align = "c", row.names = FALSE) %>%
    kable_styling(full_width = FALSE) %>%
    column_spec(1, bold = TRUE) %>%
    collapse_rows(columns = 5:7, valign = "middle")

#make table 5
table5<- kable(df_table[order(df_table$cluster, as.numeric(df_table$properties)),c(4,1,2,5,7,6)], align = "c", row.names = FALSE) %>%
    kable_styling(full_width = FALSE) %>%
    column_spec(1, bold = TRUE) %>%
    collapse_rows(columns = 4:6, valign = "middle")

#make graph1
vars = c("Longitude", "Latitude")
plot1<-fviz_cluster(list(data = df_Q1, cluster = clusters), choose.var=vars)

#make graph2
plot2<-ggplot(data=df_Q1,  aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude,  color=factor(clusters))) +  geom_point()

#make graph3
vars = c("Latitude", "Longitude")
plot3<-fviz_cluster(list(data = df_Q1, cluster = clusters), choose.var=vars)

#make graph4
plot(clusters)
plot4 <- recordPlot()


# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    titlePanel (title = h2 ("Clusters for agricultural properties")),

    sidebarLayout (
        sidebarPanel (
            h2 ("Cluster generation"),

            radioButtons ("filter1", h3 ("Potential biogas productions"),
                          choices = list ("Select all properties" = 1,
                                          "Exclude properties that produce less than L and more than S" = 2),
                          selected = 1),



            radioButtons ("filter2", h3 ("Coverage between clusters"),
                          choices = list ("Insert all clusters" = 1,
                                          "Exclude with mean less than L and greater than S" = 2),
                          selected = 1),
        ),

        mainPanel (
            uiOutput("table"),
            plotOutput("plot")
        )))
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    my_data <- eventReactive(input$filter1, {
        if (input$filter1 == 1) {
            my_table <- table1
            my_plot <- plot1
           } else {
           my_table <- table2
           my_plot <- plot2
        }
        return(list(table = my_table, plot = my_plot))
    })

    output$table <- renderUI(HTML(my_data()[["table"]]))

    output$plot <- renderPlot(my_data()[["plot"]])

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplified version use can adapt for your own use. This works with example data from your previous question.

You can add `uiOutput` and `plotOutput` to your `ui` to show the table and plot.

In `server`, you can add an `eventReactive` expression to determine what should be displayed when the radio button changes. The `table1`, `plot1`, `table2`, `plot2` should be your plots and tables for the two conditions. This assumes your tables are HTML produced by `kable`.

**Edit**: I added what you need below for `table1` and `plot1` from your example. Just assign the `kable` output to `table1` and you're set for displaying the table in shiny. It won't be reactive, but this is just a starting point.

As for the plot, with base R you would need to use `recordPlot()` or or `gridGraphics`. If you use `ggplot2` which I think you were planning, then all you need to do is `plot1 <- ggplot(data = ...` and you're set for `plot1`. Again, in this case, it won't be reactive, and `recordPlot()` is not a good long-term solution (it just stores the current plot to replay or use later), but it should work as a starting point for your demo.

```
library(shiny)
library(kableExtra)
library(ggplot2)

#copy other code here needed for df_table, clusters, etc.

#make table1
table1 <- kable(df_table[order(df_table$cluster, as.numeric(df_table$properties)),c(5,2,3,4,1,6,7)], align = "c", row.names = FALSE) %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = FALSE) %>%
  column_spec(1, bold = TRUE) %>%
  collapse_rows(columns = 5:7, valign = "middle")

#make plot1
plot(clusters)
plot1 <- recordPlot()

ui <- fluidPage (

  titlePanel (title = h1 ("Model for the formation of agricultural property clusters", align = "center")),

  sidebarLayout (
    sidebarPanel (
      h2 ("Cluster generation"),

      radioButtons ("filter1", h3 ("Potential biogas productions"),
                    choices = list ("Select all properties" = 1,
                                    "Exclude properties that produce less than L and more than S" = 2),
                    selected = 1),
    ),

    mainPanel (
      textOutput ("nclusters"),
      textOutput ("abran"),
      textOutput ("bio"),

      uiOutput("table"),
      plotOutput("plot")
    )))


# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function (input, output, session) {

  my_data <- eventReactive(input$filter1, {
    if (input$filter1 == 1) {
      my_table <- table1
      my_plot <- plot1
    } else {
      my_table <- table2
      my_plot <- plot2
    }
    return(list(table = my_table, plot = my_plot))
  })

  output$table <- renderUI(HTML(my_data()[["table"]]))

  output$plot <- renderPlot(my_data()[["plot"]])

}

# Run the application
shinyApp (ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ben. I'm new to shiny, how do I define the tables and graphs that I want to show from the shiny code, that is, how in shiny does it get the desired tables and graphs? Do I need to leave the codes corresponding to the table and graph that I presented in the question somewhere in the shiny code? Thankss

Comment: There's a lot to this, I would go through the [tutorial](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/) if you haven't already, and review info on [scoping rules](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html). For now, to make it simpler and make sure it works, you can start out just putting all your table/plot code in your .R file outside of `server` somewhere. A lot would depend where you want objects to be available, how data is stored, what reactivity you want for certain elements, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answers Ben. I will check out the sites you sent me. In fact I would like to just display the tables and figures that I got from my R script in shiny code.

Comment: Thanks Ben for all the help. I improved my question regarding the problem I want to solve. I adjusted the shiny code according to your guidelines. I inserted the executable code of the Script I want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212023/discussion-between-ben-and-jovani-souza).

Comment: Ben, would you know how to help me with the questions that I entered above? Thanksss

Comment: @JovaniSouza The short answer is that this is possible. But if you're looking for additional code, I would recommend making this a new question on SO and removing from this question. You will have higher likelihood of getting an answer quicker. I might not get a chance to look at more closely until later in week.

Comment: Ben, Please, could you take a look at two questions asked by my brother Jose:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61595335/find-the-shortest-path-between-points-on-a-map-made-by-the-leaflet-package

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61591674/general-function-to-insert-the-colors-of-the-clusters-in-my-map-made-by-the-leaf

We are working together. Thank you very much friend.